# I am not able to pull all github branchs to local repositry?

Tags: git, github

I have cloned my NextJs project from GitHub, but am not able to pull all branches' code into the local repositry. the project was 5 months older.

I cloned using like

```
git clone <git url>
```

I have tried these things to pull code from remote branches

```
(base) Apples-MBP:nextjs-one apple$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  origin/main
  origin/redux
  origin/uione
(base) Apples-MBP:nextjs-one apple$ git fetch
(base) Apples-MBP:nextjs-one apple$ git checkout redux
Branch 'redux' set up to track remote branch 'redux' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'redux'
(base) Apples-MBP:nextjs-one apple$ git pull origin redux
From https://github.com/airKing05/nextjs-one
 * branch            redux      -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

please provide me with the best solution to get my origin branch code into the local repository. I want to pull all branches `redux and uione` without merging to `main` from GitHub.

Comment: Looks like you updated the local tracking branches before you checked out `redux`, so it was pointing to the already-up-to-date remote branch

Comment: Your `git fetch` step already updated you to the latest. Since it printed nothing, nothing had changed since your earlier `git clone`. If you expected something to change, perhaps you are cloning and fetching the wrong repository (an inactive one, vs the one people are actually using).

Comment: I am new in git so what should I do know to pull other branches to local